# How to change text of Label in UITableView based on button pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in `ViewController` which displays `Default`, five times on running in the simulator based on the following code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! OutsideCell
          myCell.titleLabel.text = "Default"
    return myCell
    }

    @IBAction func firstButtonPressed(_ sender: Any){


    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

I also have 2 buttons at the bottom of `ViewController` and 
I like to display text as `First Button` when `firstButtonPressed` and `Second Button` when `secondButtonPressed` instead of `Default` in `UITableView`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each cell of the table view when the button is tapped.

```
for cell in myTableView.visibleCells() {
   cell.titleLabel?.text = "First Button"
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it, that works is there anyway I can make the First Button to appear when view loads for first time instead of Default?

Comment: In your cellForRow function, just use another text value there instead of Default.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a generic method as `eventButtonPressed` and use the tag attribute to determine which button is pressed through the storyboard.

```
@IBAction func eventButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
       //First Button
    } else if (sender.tag == 1) {
       //Second Button
    }
}
```

You can use switch operand if you have many cases.

```
switch sender.tag {
   case 0:
      print("First button pressed")
   case 1:
      print("Second button pressed")
   default:
     print("Default button pressed")
}
```

Hope it helps,